# Allowing RAR (Read after Read) with pthreads

Tags: multithreading, locking, pthreads, mutex

I have a hash map shared across multiple threads that needs to be locked when different threads read/write to the hash map.  However, writes occur very infrequently, about once per hour, but can occur at any time.  Reads occur very frequently, at around 10000 reads/second.  Reads can be performed in parallel since they don't modify the data structure, but in my current implementation, I lock during both reads and writes to prevent WAR, RAW, and WAW conflicts.  However, almost all the time I am going to have RAR conflicts which don't actually cause a problem.  What is the best way that I can lock a mutex only for reading or only for writing to allow RAR to occur concurrently?

Comment: Are you looking for [Reader-Writer lock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_rwlock_init.html)?

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for!  If I could make your comment an answer, I would.